# How to catch exception after DataBind event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling, sqldatasource

I have next code:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // some code-------------------
       sourceDetails.SelectCommand += "<new condition>";
       this.DataBind();
    }
```

`sourceDetails` is an `SqlDataSource` object in .aspx page, which has query to database.

`"<new condition>"` - condition which changes.

If condition is incorrect I get an error on my page. I want to catch error before it will appear.

Comment: ...you mean like a `try..catch`.. ?

Comment: Simon Whitehead, yes.

Comment: How about - test your code with all possible conditions, so your users will never see the exceptions?

Comment: What do you want to do after catch exception? show another page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for attention on my question! I found next solution:
1. SqlDataSource has event OnSelected. I had used it.
2. I wrote this code in OnSelected event:

```
protected void sourceDetails_Selected(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Exception != null)
        {
            //Doing what we need to do
        }
    }
```

`SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs` contains all data that we need for cathing exception and handling it: `Exception` and `Command` properties.

Answer (score 0):

This will alert the error:

```
try
{
    // some code-------------------
    sourceDetails.SelectCommand += "<new condition>";
    this.DataBind();
}
catch (SqlException e)
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Alert", "alert('" + e.Message + "');", true);
}
```

Comment: try {} catch {} doesn't helpful. At first I use OracleClient, and secondly - it's performing without exception in Page_Load event.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle overview post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) there are specific [events for data binding handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#data_binding_events_for_databound_controls). Perhaps you could use these life cycle hooks ([DataBinding event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.databinding.aspx) or [DataBound event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.databound.aspx)) to prevent an error or even better to handle it.

Hope I helped!